# Thinset not drying

Tags: tile

I've done tile before, but never used a premix mortar before. Typically I'd lay one day, grout the next. I had a small area in the basement about 5'x18" to replace with 6" tiles. I scrubbed the concrete first and let it dry over night. Then I thought I'd save time buying this [premixed stuff](https://www.menards.com/main/flooring-rugs/tile-stone/tile-installation-maintenance/tile-mortar-mastics/tec-reg-ultimate-premixed-mortar-130-1-gal/7046165011/p-1444432119182-c-6586.htm).

I installed 6x6 tiles with a 3/16" grout line. It's been 36 hours now and the tiles can still move. The bucket said it'd take about 6 hours to dry, maybe longer depending on conditions.

Is this stuff ever going to dry?

The basement stays cool but dry. It's a walkout basement, but I haven't needed a dehumidifier. I thought about picking up a box fan to see if that helps dry quicker.

Comment: Was the premixed stuff past its shelf date?  If you read the instructions it says 24 hours but that it may take longer, especially on floors.

Comment: Thinset normally drys by hydration.  it’s hard to guess, I have never used a pre mix thin set product I would contact the manufacturer, possibly re read the instructions.it says may fail if damp and the bucket is good for 1 year from date of MFG, then 6 months after opening. And not to use water.